# How to unlock the bootloader of Samsung galaxy grand 2?

Tags: samsung, fastboot, bootloader, lineageos, bootloader-lock

I searched the whole internet and couldn't find any guide for unlocking the bootloader of this specific model. my main goal is to install Lineage OS but the instructions on the page don't seem to be for this device.

**Page Link:** https://lineageosroms.com/ms013g/

(can't find a way to make fastboot find my device - it seems grand 2 doesn't have an actual fastboot mode. it has a download mode).

It says you need to enable OEM in developer mode but there is no such an option available.

I've also found a TWRP for my device here: https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/twrp-v3-2-3-0-for-galaxy-grand-2-sm-g7102-unofficial-updated.3778414/page-2

do I need to unlock the bootloader to replace it with the recovery mode of device?

Comment: Is your phone a branded device or somehow bound to a certain mobile network operator? That could explain the missing unlock option.

Comment: What do you mean by branded device?

Comment: TWRP is available for my device and everyone is installing it. but I don't know how did they figured out how to unlock this phone.

Comment: by the meaning of branded phone I don't actually think my phone is branded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this device is not bootloader locked

Comment: "Volume down + power + middle button" takes me to download mode and "Volume up + power + middle button" takes me to recovery mode. I want to flash TWRP and install lineage OS on it. which one is the bootloader?

Comment: OK adb reboot bootloader works. thanks.